# Starting rsync command on every hour

Tags: linux, bash, rsync

im new in linux just want to asking you :
How to add this command to start every hour on the computer :
rsync -a --ignore-existing 130.68.124.219:/home/pi/Desktop/* /home/pi/test/

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Create cron job

`crontab -e`

Select an editor. (first time only)

Write the string in the opened editor window:

```
0 * * * * rsync -a --ignore-existing 130.68.124.219:/home/pi/Desktop/* /home/pi/test/
```

Save changes.
That's all.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a lookat https://www.arubacloud.com/tutorial/how-to-configure-a-backup-with-rsync.aspx
This page will help you in configuring a crontab.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).